# How to automatically discover and add users via LDAP in SonarQube?

Tags: ldap, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I guess this question basically boils down to some misunderstanding that I have about how the SonarQube LDAP plugin works in general. We have integrated the LDAP plugin and our users are authenticating against our corporate LDAP server. When we we want to create a new group and add users to that group for a new project, we have assumed that the users themselves must authenticate into SonarQube first so they get added as a user to SonarQube. After that, then we are able to put them into the appropriate groups that they belong to. This is a pain for our administrators since the people that need to be added are logging in at differing times or forgetting to log in at all. What we would like is something that Nexus provides where we can do a lookup of that user's account id, then add them and place them into the appropriate group(s). In that way, the user is not bothered by having to login first and then the administrator has to give the privileges and then the user logs out and logs back in. Is this a misunderstanding on my part? I ask because when I go to the users page and click on 'Create New User' it not only asks for the user's id but also the user's password which I obviously don't know so this is telling me that this will be a local account.

Comment: This would require that the scm subsystem be modified so that it triggers an identity lookup on any unsuccessful user lookup during blame assignment.

Answer (score 1):

By default SonarQube's LDAP plugin works like you think it does. You can configure [LDAP group mapping](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin#LDAPPlugin-GroupMapping) so that when the user enrolls, he/she is automatically added to the appropriate group.

In other words, create the group for the project in SonarQube, and then create the same group in LDAP and add users to it. Then when users login for the first time they will be in the appropriate group, and on each subsequent login any group changes will be reflected in SonarQube.

This, in my opinion, is infact better than adding users manually.